# HTTP request in Azure Data Factory

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I need to tap into a HTTP requests via URL using the HTTP connector. I was able to do this as well as setup the dataset. Where I'm having issues is on the pipeline. Here's what I need to do. What is the best way to accomplish this?

1. Call out to the service base URL and retrieve the header returned of TotalPages.
2. Using the value for TotalPages, make subsequent requests to the URL with the parameter page (e.g., page=1, page=2, etc.) using the value from TotalPages to form those requests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the issue here is that you cannot nest control structures in Data Factory more than 1 time. The solution is to create two or more pipelines (aka Master and Child).

From the Master pipeline retrieve the number of tasks you will need to execute, and pass them to a for loop. Within the for loop launch for each activity pair a new Child pipeline which will then execute the second activity.

If the Activity is simple enough you can skip the Child Pipeline altogether and do it directly inside the first for loop.

As a Json representation of pipelines in question it should look along these lines:

```
{
"name": "generic_master",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Web1",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Web1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Web1').output",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                        "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "pipeline": {
                                "referenceName": "generic_child",
                                "type": "PipelineReference"
                            },
                            "waitOnCompletion": true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

```
{
"name": "generic_child",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Web1",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
                "method": "POST"
            }
        }
    ],
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the TotalPages values from the HTTP Request's response, you can use a "Lookup" activity to submit the HTTP request and store the TotalPages value in a variable with the "Set variable" activity.
Actions:
Pipeline level:

- create a variable called TotalPages
  Lookup activity:
- tick the first row only box on the Settings tab
- As a source dataset, use the data set defined for your HTTP request
- Select the GET method.
  Set variable activity:
- Select the TotalPages variable on the Variables tab
- In the value box, click on "Add dynamic content" and enter something like this: @{activity('GetTotalPages').output.firstRow.RegisterSearch['@TotalPages']}

In my case, the lookup activity is called GetTotalPages, and my HTTP request returns the total number of pages in a RegisterSearch array, under a column name @TotalPages